# Validation of Clustering with labels

Tags: clustering, cross-validation, validation, graph-theory

I am currently trying to perform clustering on 8 different datasets where I have 40-100 "labeled" data points per data set, representing which data points belong to the same cluster. I further have several thousand unlabeled data points.

The difference between data points in the 8 different datasets are bigger than the difference within the datasets (think 8 different animal families, each containing several races). The same model will be used for all of the different datasets (as there are way more than these 8 animal families - the real number of datasets are unknown, and a model for each dataset is not feasible)

How do I validate which method is performing better in this setting where the labels are not necessarily 100% correct (In the hierarchical sense, we could have more or less clusters. Also within each animal family there might be more races than within our ground truth sets). I currently use Adjusted Mutual Information and Adjusted Rand Index as my metrics

**Q1. Is there a way to do cross validation in this setting - or any other validation method, such that i do not overfit to the labeled data**

Another approach I have taken is by constructing a graph (animal as node and some similarity measure as edge weight) for each dataset, by using some similarity measure. I can then use a community detection algorithm like Louvain to seperate data points in "clusters". In this setting splitting the datasets in lesser fractions seems even harder, as the algorithm depends on the weights between the different nodes.

**Q2. Is there a way to do cross validation in this setting?**